# using subqueries on example (find all orders from the customer with condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I've got a problem with some query. What I need to do is write out all the orders from the customer with the highest number of orders (from one table).

So I got this (it works and tell me which customer have the highest number of orders):

```
SELECT custid, COUNT(*) as "Number of orders"
FROM sales.orders
GROUP BY custid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

And then I need to combine this with another query that gives me all "ORDERID" from this customers orders. I try different approaches, but nothings works fine. Finally I've got something like this:

```
SELECT custid, orderid FROM sales.orders
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT custid, COUNT(*) as "Number of orders"
    FROM sales.orders
    GROUP BY custid
)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

With error:

> "'SALES.ORDERS.custid' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

How can I use subqueries in this case to make it work? Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: Is sales your database name or part of table name?

Comment: What happens when you delete ", COUNT(*) as "Number of orders" <- you dont need this anyways because you wont see it in your result

Comment: What db are you using? MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: @kentor: when I remove this I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I use SQL-Server (2008).

Comment: @Edrich yep, this table name is "sales.orders"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT custid,
       orderid
FROM   sales.orders
WHERE  custid = (SELECT TOP 1 custid
                 FROM   sales.orders
                 GROUP  BY custid
                 ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT custid, orderid FROM sales.orders
WHERE custid IN(
SELECT TOP 1 custid
FROM sales.orders
GROUP BY custid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

This should work (for MySQL), here a SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d580a6/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will also try this solution.

Comment: dont forget to use sales.orders as tablenames. I will update it, thought it is your DB name

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP 1
        custId
    FROM sales.orders
    GROUP BY custId
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
)
SELECT
    c.custId
    o.orderId
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN sales.orders o
    on o.custId = c.custId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will also try your solution.